# Same value from the interactive shell

Tags: python, django, interactive

```
def unittest(execute=False):
                with timetravel(datetime(2017,03,01)) as now:
                    loan2 = compute_loan(user, {'product_id': 1,
                                       'frequency': '1week',
                                       'first_debit_date': now })

            if not execute:
                print('You are wrong')
                pass
            else:
                field_list = CustomerProduct._meta.get_fields()
                mylist = []
                exclude = ['id','contract', 'actor_actions',
                        'locked', 'description', 'target_actions',
                        'action_object_actions', 'created', 'modified',
                        'request', 'withdrawal_first_date', 'deposit_date']
                table = Texttable(max_width = 6000)
                for field in field_list:
                    if field.name not in exclude:
                        mylist.append([field.name, getattr(loan2.request.customer_product, field.name)])
                table.add_rows(mylist)
                print(table.draw())
```

With this function, I created a list of list containing `field.name` and `getattr(loan2.request.customer_product, field.name)`. For example,

```
+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| debit_frequency                                    | 1week   |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| broker_pmt                                         | 17.865  |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| broker_pre_withdrawal_daily_interest_rate          | 0.001   |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
| broker_total_post_pre_withdrawal_interest_amount   | 139.908 |
+----------------------------------------------------+---------+
```

The problem is I prefer something like

```
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| debit_frequency                                    | u'1week'        |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| broker_pmt                                         | 17.865903434    |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| broker_pre_withdrawal_daily_interest_rate          | 0.0014348934    |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| broker_total_post_pre_withdrawal_interest_amount   | 139.9083498304  |
+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

In fact, those values are the same when I query the database with something like

```
In [7]: loaner.request.customer.sum_new_pmt
Out[7]: 56.000121522936645
```

I would like the returning value from the interactive shell. Could anyone help me with this issue? What could I modify in the code?

Thanks!

**P.S.** Please let me know if the question is unclear.

Comment: The values are the same.  The difference is that the interavtive shell is printing the `repr` of the value.

Comment: @cco Yes ok, but with this code, I'd like to print the repr. Are you able to modify the code to allow such thing?

Comment: It's hard to know what to suggest without knowing anything about `Texttable`, but i'd think that using `mylist.append([field.name, repr(getattr(loan2.request.customer_product, field.name))])` might do the trick.

Comment: @cco You are almost right, but it didn't show up all the decimals. with this new structure, it appended `Decimal('...')` and `u'...'`, but it didn't show up all the appropriate decimal. The purpose of that is I want to use the assertEqual function in unit-tests. So I need the exact value in argument. For instance, `self.assertEqual(loaner.request.customer.sum_new_pmt, 56.000)` is wrong while `self.assertEqual(loaner.request.customer.sum_new_pmt, 56.000121522936645)` is right

Comment: I think the sanest way to do the comparison would be to round floats (both expected and computed) to a particular precision before comparing them.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean in using the instance I use in my last comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Expanding on my comments)
First, I'd suggest not print your test results the way you show.  There are several test modules for Python; my choice would be [Pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/).

Since conversion from strings to float doesn't always give the exact value corresponding to the string (because binary floating point can't represent the value exactly), when comparing floating-point numbers it is best to avoid comparing for equality, but to allow some wiggle room.  My suggestion was to use `round` (or equivalently, string formatting to a particular precision) for this - e.g. `assert round(139.908, 3) == round(computed_value, 3)`.

[What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) is a good explanation of the issues, with some useful code.

Comment: Yes, but assertEqual for Django for the moment

Answer (score 0):

As per TextTable source code here https://github.com/foutaise/texttable/blob/master/texttable.py#L304 It seems you should be using something like this

```
....
table = Texttable(max_width = 6000)
table.set_precision(20)
....
```